# Shifting binary number in c++

Tags: c++, binary, operation, byte-shifting

For example I want to do:
I have 1 it is 00000001 in binary.
and when I shift like 1<<3 I'll take 8 it is 00001000.
So, I need that I take 00001111 after 1<<3.
I wish you understand if something wrong add unclear ask about it please.
I want to do shorter this part:

`for(int i=1;h>0;h--,i*=2) hr+=i;`

Comment: `(1 << 4 ) - 1` would give you expected result.

Comment: I flagged typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you want

```
std::uint32_t my_shift(std::uint32_t n, std::uint32_t lshift)
{
    return (n << lshift) | ((1 << lshift) - 1);
//      original shifted | 0b0001111 (lshift 1)
}
```

Comment: Kinda sounds like they just want `(1 << lshift) | ((1 << lshift) - 1)`

Answer (score 1):

You can directly iterate hr:

```
for(int hr=1; h>0; h--, hr=2*hr+1)
```

Comment: No i need solution with binary opertions. But it is cool too.